# When null is passed into generic method, strangely I can still get the type

Tags: c#, generics, typeof

I  was playing with some generics, and I found out something by accident that is really interesting. Please have a look at the code at this line Console.WriteLine(testClass1.Contains(testClass)); which produces output: true. Which I have no idea why because the class is assign to null, and when I step into the code, I can see that null is passed in.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassWithGenericMethod testClass1 = new ClassWithGenericMethod();
        TestClass testClass = null;

        Console.WriteLine(testClass1.Contains(testClass));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class ClassWithGenericMethod
    {
        public bool Contains<T>(T entity)
        {
            return typeof(T).Name == "TestClass";
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
    }
```

So how does it know the correct type on this line  return typeof(T).Name == "TestClass";  ?

Comment: AFAIK Because the generic is resolved at compile time

Comment: yes - try entity.GetType() and you will see quite different behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it in layman's term, the generic method is actually a kind of function template (or "definition") and the "real" method will be constructed from that definition. For example, if you call the method like

```
Contains<string>(null);
```

The .NET compiler will ensure the following method construction (or somewhat similar)

```
public bool Contains(string entity)
{
    return typeof(string).Name == "TestClass";
}
```

You can see that all `T`s are replaced with `string`, which makes it perfectly legal for the method to use `T` type and and does not require runtime-checking of the `entity` parameter at all.

Answer (score 4):

Types for generic methods are not resolved at run-time, they are resolved at compile time. The compiler knows that when you call `Contains<T>` you are calling it with an argument of type `TestClass` so the compiler uses the completed generic method `Contains<TestClass>`. Whether the value is null or not is a run-time condition which has nothing to do with the knowledge the compiler has when compiling the code.